# Use of MaskedEditExtender with decimal point

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax extender controls with asp.net 3.5 in particular MaskedEditExtender.

My settinngs are:

Mask = 99.99

InputDirection = RighttoLeft

MaskType = number.

I can't seem to achieve what I want which is to set the focus just to the left of the decimal point. I try both InputDirection RightToLeft and LeftToRight. They both have problematic behavior. The example given by Microsoft on their web site, is close to want I want but I cannot achieve these results.

See http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx, first example.

Thanks in advance.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I am not answering your question directly, but I thought it would be worth mentioning this alternative, which might not exhibit the problem you are having:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/